# Adding additional data on a vb.net chart

Tags: vb.net, charts, pie-chart

Is there a way to add the winning value on a vb.net chart in the whitespace around the chart.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can just put a label on it?

Comment: I just ended up putting a label at the bottom of the form.